# How to get the selector working on a trivia game in React?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I am making a trivia game in react using the Open Trivia Database API and I am trying to get it so there is a selector button and when it drops down it will show you a list of categories and when you click on it, it will give you a question from said category. I feel like I am close but am just missing a piece and was wondering if someone could spot it or just point me in the right direction? Thank you in advance for your time and help.

Here is my code for app.js:

```
import React from 'react'
import './App.css'
// import axios from 'axios'
import Questions from './components/questions'
import Categories from './components/categories'
import categorySelector from './components/categorySelector'

class App extends React.Component {
  constructor (props) {
    super(props)
    this.state = {
      questions: [],
      categories: []
      // score: 0,

    }
  }

  render () {
    return (
      <div className='App'>
        <h2>Trivia Game</h2>
        <categorySelector
          categories={Categories}
          onSelect={event => this.questions(event.target.value)}
        />

      </div>
    )
  }
}
export default App
```

And here is my code for categorySelector.js:

```
import React from 'react'

class categorySelector extends React.Component {
  render () {
    const { categories, onSelect } = this.props

    return (
      <div class='categorySelector'>
        <select
          value={categories} onChange={onSelect}
        >
          <option value=''>-- No category selected --</option>
          {categories.map(category => (
            <option value={category} key={category.id}>{category.name}</option>
          ))}
        </select>
      </div>
    )
  }
}

export default categorySelector
```

Comment: `<select value={categories} onChange={onSelect}>` I don't think it will take `categories` as array, try using something like `categories[0]` or `state`-variables

Comment: I will try that! Thank you!

Comment: Ive got it working in this fiddle, you just need to add mroe categories and questions https://jsfiddle.net/x67nkd5z/54/

Comment: Wow thank you so much for taking the time!! Extremely helpful Max!!

Answer (score 2):

It looks like the select tag does not take a value prop: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/select

I modified your return statement as follows

- change 'class' to 'className' as class is a reserved keyword in Reactjs
- removed value prop from select tag
- updated the value prop in the options tag to be the category name instead of object

```
    return (
      <div class='categorySelector'>
        <select onChange={onSelect}>
          <option value=''>-- No category selected --</option>
          {categories.map(category => (
            <option value={category.name} key={category.id}>{category.name}</option>
          ))}
        </select>
      </div>
    )
```

I also suggest capitalizing react class names such as CategorySelector instead of categorySelector.

There's a couple typo's in the App component

- You're passing the Categories component as a prop instead of passing the categories slice of state.
- In the onSelect event, this.questions(...) implies you're calling a method. However it doesn't look like you have a questions method written.
  Instead, if you want to 'save' the selected category in the questions list you can call setState like so:
- The code inside the brackets adds the selected value without removing previous selections.

  ```
    <categorySelector
      categories={this.categories}
      onSelect={event => this.setState({questions: [...this.state.questions, event.target.value]})}
    />
  ```

Comment: Would probably be a good idea to store the selected question and category in the state somewhere, as in my jsFiddle above, this can be extended to select a question at random, or have another dropbox with more questions, if you want to select a whole set of questions instead of just one, depends which direction the project wants to go .

Comment: Probably also a good idea to extract the onSelect function into a handler function as its a little but unwieldy for a one liner

Comment: Thank you !! I will try and make these changes

Comment: Agreed @max-carroll, to extract the function place it between the constructor and render like so:
selectCategoryHandle = () => { this.setState(questions: [...this.state.questions, event.target.value])}
Then update the onSelect like so "onSelect={this.selectCategoryHandle}"